# OCaml: What do brackets surrounding an expression mean [x]?

Tags: ocaml

```
(* Example #1: *)
let rec product l1 l2 =
    match l1, l2 with
    | [], _ | _, [] -> []
    | h1::t1, h2::t2 -> (h1,h2)::(product [h1] t2)@(product t1 l2);;

(* Example #2: *)
let rec rev l =
  match l with [] -> []
  |   x::xs -> rev xs @ [x];;
```

What does [h1] and [x] mean in the examples above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `e` is an expression of type `'a`, then `[e]` has type `'a list`, and just corresponds to an alternative notation for `e :: []`.

This syntactic sugar also works for lists containing several elements, namely:
 `[a; b]` is an alternative notation for `a :: b :: []`.

As an aside, note that *this notation can also be used within pattern-maching*, for example the function `last` returning the last element of a list can be written like this:

```
let rec last l = 
  match l with
  | [] -> failwith "last"
  | [x] -> x
  | _ :: l -> last l
```